# Importing CSVs into separate Excel Tabs (overwriting on a daily basis) from a defined file path?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am an extremely novice user of VBA and I am trying to important a list of CSV files (they change every, but are static) into an excel spreadsheet using different tabs.

The code I found and was using is public:

```
Sub CombineCsvFiles()
'updateby Extendoffice
Dim xFilesToOpen As Variant
Dim I As Integer
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xTempWb As Workbook
Dim xDelimiter As String
Dim xScreen As Boolean
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
xDelimiter = "|"
xFilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv), *.csv", , "Kutools for Excel", , True)
If TypeName(xFilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
    MsgBox "No files were selected", , "Kutools for Excel"
    GoTo ExitHandler
End If
I = 1
Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
xTempWb.Sheets(1).Copy
Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
xTempWb.Close False
Do While I < UBound(xFilesToOpen)
    I = I + 1
    Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
    xTempWb.Sheets(1).Move , xWb.Sheets(xWb.Sheets.Count)
Loop
ExitHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
Set xWb = Nothing
Set xTempWb = Nothing
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description, , "Kutools for Excel"
Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

While it works, the problem is I have to select the folders directly. What I'd rather have is defining the file name and automatically overwriting the existing data. Any thoughts/examples of where to point me?

Comment: Could you elaborate on *"What I'd rather have is defining the file name and automatically overwriting the existing data."*?  Maybe lay out an exact plan with the workbook and worksheet names e.g. open workbook `Test.csv` in folder `C:\Test` and copy it as worksheet `Test` in the workbook containing this code....

Answer (score 0):

xFilesToOpen is defined as an array variant. If you are selecting multiple files, so it is returning an array of strings denoting the selected file paths.

If the filenames and paths remain constant, you can simply hard code those file path strings into the array

> Dim xFilesToOpen() As Variant
>
> xFilesToOpen() = Array("C:\path\to\file1.csv", "C:\path\to\file2.csv")

then remove the file selection code:

> xFilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),
> *.csv", , "Kutools for Excel", , True) If TypeName(xFilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
> MsgBox "No files were selected", , "Kutools for Excel"
> GoTo ExitHandler End If

and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, you want to import multiple text files into multiple sheets, right. The code below will do that for you.

```
Sub CombineTextFiles()

    Dim xFilesToOpen As Variant
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xTempWb As Workbook
    Dim xDelimiter As String
    Dim xScreen As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xDelimiter = "|"
    xFilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", , "Kutools for Excel", , True)
    If TypeName(xFilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No files were selected"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If
    I = 1
    Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
    xTempWb.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    xTempWb.Close False
    xWb.Worksheets(I).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
    Do While I < UBound(xFilesToOpen)
        I = I + 1
        Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
        With xWb
            xTempWb.Sheets(1).Move after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(I).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
              Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
              TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
              ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
              Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
              Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
              Other:=True, OtherChar:=xDelimiter
        End With
    Loop
ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
    Set xWb = Nothing
    Set xTempWb = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, , "Kutools for Excel"
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```